# How to return NULL from a select-where-in postgresql query when the record does not exist in the array?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query

```sql
select * 
from table1 as t
where t.id in ('1', '2')
```

If both records are the my result is `[1, 2]`.
If only record #1 is there my result is `[1]`.

But if only record #1 is there how can I make the result be `[1, NULL]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `VALUES` and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM (VALUES ('1'), ('2')) s(c)
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t
  ON t.id = s.c;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8fa500c78e01d1169ca810cc9b9488e2)**

Comment: This does seem to work... however, i am having trouble as i simplified the question too much.. the values were not 1 & 2  but instead were `1e4fd2c5-c32e-4e3f-91b3-45478bcf0185` and `1e4fd2c5-c32e-4e3f-91b3-45478bcf0186`  of type UUID.   if gives error -> ERROR:  operator does not exist: uuid = text
LINE 4:   ON f.fp_id = s.c
                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.  *****  I will select this but where would i have to cast to become uuid?

Comment: @Justacoder `ON t.id = s.c::uuid` **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=99b69e8444d587f2a04d1c5036034fc8)**